# Conditions and pointers

Tags: c, conditional-statements

If I have something like this

```
    if(pointer!=NULL&&(*pointer)==x) { ... }
```

Will it segfault if pointer is NULL? If it is compiler specific, I'd like to know how it is in GCC.

Comment: sidenote: `if(pointer != NULL)` is equivalent to `if(pointer)`

Comment: Sidenote 2: I prefer `if (NULL != pointer)`, `if (NULL == pointer)`, ...

Comment: side note 3: I prefer `if(NULL!=pointer)` rather than `if(NULL==pointer)`, `unequal` makes it noticed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, because of [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

If the LHS is *false*, then the RHS won't be evaluated. Therefore, if it's a `NULL` pointer, it will never hit the RHS and attempt to dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

If `&&` is used, second condition will be executed only if first condition is `TRUE`. This will never leads to segmentation fault.

Same kind of check we can do with `||` also.

```
if ((pstr_buf == NULL)  || (pstr_buf[0] == '\0'))
{
   printf("\ninvalid string buffer\n");
}
```